# RTTI não retornando função no getMethods

Tags: delphi

tenho a seguinte classe

```
   TClasse = class
   public
      Funcao: function(arg: String): Integer; stdcall;
   end;
```

O que acontece, é que ao usar RTTI nessa classe para retornar a função "Funcao", ele não trás por ser setado como "nil", tem algum jeito de retornar essa função?

Código do RTTI:

```
   function GetFunctionName(FuncPointer: Pointer):PAnsiChar;
   type
      PIInterface = ^IInterface;
   var
      obj: TObject;
      Ctx: TRttiContext;
      RttiType: TRttitype;
      Method: TRttiMethod;
   begin

      obj := PIInterface(@FuncPointer)^ as TInterfacedObject;
      RttiType := Ctx.GetType(obj.ClassType);
      for method in RttiType.GetMethods do
      begin
         if method.CodeAddress = funcPointer then
            result := PAnsiChar(method.name);
      end;
   end;
```

Comment: Podes postar o código (*RTTI*) que você está usando para extrair as funções da classe?

Comment: @Andrey acabo de atualizar